# Simplification of multi-index notation of the dot product of a non-constant vector and the nabla operator $(a(\vec{x})\nabla )^\alpha f(\vec{x})=?$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion, index-notation

Is there a known simplification for the multi-index notation of
$$ 
(\vec{v}\cdot \vec{A})^kf(\vec{x}) =\sum_{|\alpha|=k} \frac{k!}{\alpha!} (\vec{v} \circ \vec{A})^\alpha f(\vec{x}) = \sum_{|\alpha|=k} \frac{k!}{\alpha!}(\vec{v} \circ a(\vec{x})\vec{\nabla} )^\alpha f(\vec{x}) = ?
$$
with the linear (vector) operator $ \vec{A} f(\vec{x}):=\left[a(\vec{x})\vec{\nabla} \right] f(\vec{x})$. Note that the scalar coefficient $a(\vec{x})$ has a spatial dependency.  The goal is to find an expression with the multi-index notation of the nabla operator $\partial^\alpha$. For simplicity, the problem is restricted to $\alpha = (\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$.  Thus the vectors and vector operators are two dimensional.

For the special case $a=const.$ we have
$\sum_{|\alpha|=k} \frac{k!}{\alpha!}(\vec{v} \circ a(\vec{x})\vec{\nabla} )^\alpha f(\vec{x}) = \sum_{|\alpha|=k} \frac{k!}{\alpha!}\vec{v}^\alpha a^\alpha \partial^\alpha f(\vec{x})$.

Note that problem drops out from an power series expansion of the operator exponential $e^{\vec{v}\cdot \vec{A}} f(\vec{x})$.

Comment: What's wrong with $a\partial^\alpha f$?

Comment: I reformulated the problem slightly and hope that it answers your question. The problem is that $a(\vec{x})$ has a spatial dependency and that the nabla operator acts on it.